# Symfony flag-toggling entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

I want to ask, is it possible to have "Flagception - Feature toggle bundle", to have entities ignored in doctrine migrations?
I have a huge project, which I have to reuse many times. I can simply use it, flag unnecessary elements and it is pretty much ready, but doctrine migrations are still using unused entities, and creating tables for them. Is it possible flag specific entities, so doctrine migration would ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using doctrine dbal schema_filter option like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!prefix_)~
```

Every table starting with `prefix_` will be ignored.

More about ignoring custom tables [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#manual-tables)

Comment: Yes, this helps to ignore tables, but I need to be able to flag them, and ignore different tables each time. Any idea, how that can be achieved? I need to be able to ignore tables according to flags. For example, if I flag invoices functionality, it is ignoring Controllers which are responsible for it, But on the same time, It should ignore tables as well. In this case, I would need to manually adjust schema filter each time

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via command line no need to write in doctrine.yaml file everytime. Using this command would filter out all tables starting with foobar:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --filter-expression='~^(?!foobar)~'
```

Comment: Yes, this ignores tables, the problem is, I need foobar part to be dynamic, according to flags.

Comment: Create one another command and call above command in loop/if/else condition. You can pass dynamic value in "foobar" there. I think this is only way to fix your problem.